# How to fix leaking fonts in Firefox on Windows

Tags: fonts, nuxt.js

i am currently working on a web application and I added a specific google font "Quicksand" to my project.

On Windows when I am using Firefox, my fonts leak. I had this problem on different computers which are using Firefox in Windows.

I link here an exemple of the font, it is leaking.

[image: My problem]

My web application is using vuetify with Nuxt.

Do you have any idea where to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. My link to the google font wasn't full.
My problems appeared only when i applied bold on tags.

I had to add differents weights of the font to fix this problem.

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap Instead of https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap